# Is Not Null argument in CASE giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL Server

```
select *,
case table1.indthrud when is null then 'Current' when is not null then 'Historical' end Indicator

    from table1
```

When i try to run the above query it gives the following error

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'.*

However the below query works fine:

```
    select *,
    case  when  table1.indthru is null then 'Current' when  table1.indthru is not null then 'Historical' end Ind
    from table1
```

Can you explain why the argument cant be put in front of CASE and has to put in individual when clasue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use *simple case* syntax. In SQL-92 standard* the syntax is described as follows:

```
<simple case> ::=
     CASE <case operand>
       <simple when clause>...
       [ <else clause> ]
     END

[...]

<simple when clause> ::= WHEN <when operand> THEN <result>

[...]

<when operand> ::= <value expression>
```

And `<value expression>` is described later as:

```
<value expression> ::=
       <numeric value expression>
     | <string value expression>
     | <datetime value expression>
     | <interval value expression>
```

So basically `WHEN IS [NOT] NULL THEN` is a syntax error. You should use the *searched case* syntax:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN expr IS NULL THEN 'current'
    WHEN expr IS NOT NULL THEN 'Historical'
END
```

---

Note that when using simple case syntax, `WHEN NULL THEN` works as far as syntax is concerned but it will not produce the expected result. This:

```sql
CASE expr WHEN NULL THEN 'x'
```

according to the specs, is equivalent to:

```sql
CASE WHEN expr = NULL THEN 'x'
```

and the result of comparing NULL values using `=` operator is *unknown*.

Comment: Thank you so much Salman!

Answer (score 1):

First, your error is because `is not null` is not a value.  Your first `case` is looking for a *constant* for the comparison.  And `is not null` is not a constant.

Second, when the constant is `null`, there is still no match, because `null = null` evaluations to `null`, which is treated as false in this context.

The simplest expression for what you want would use `else`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when t1.indthru is null then 'Current' else 'Historical' end) as Ind
from table1 t1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this Gordon!

So if I understood it correctly for using the 

`
Case (argument) 
`Then the WHEN statement will be looking for a constant to compare.

And if we have to use the instances where the value is null / not null we have to include the column individually in each WHEN clause ?

Comment: @SyedAliAhmedIslam . . . Yes, I think you understand how it works.